# Linked Server from Sharepoint 2010 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting

I'm trying to create a linked server in MSSQL to SharePoint in order to be able to write some storedprocs so that I can access them in Reporting Services.

I have created the link using the following...

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LINKTOSHAREPOINT', @srvproduct=N'ACE 12.0', 
@provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @datasrc=N'http://xxxx/CustomerService/Lists/', 
@provstr=N'WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;LIST={3B85B1FA-C2C2-4D30-9DD4-0C42C6F85545}'


EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LINKTOSHAREPOINT',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=N'sa',@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

I'm as confident as I can be that the List Guid and the server names are all correct. the Linked Server appears to connect but returns only "node" level info...

Catalogs --> Default --> Tables

But everything is empty.

I'm fairly sure it feels like a security issue, but I'm again confident that the windows login I use has access to most things. 
Has anyone got any ideas or has even had this sort of thing working?

Comment: do you get any error message? since sharepoint has no clue of sql users did you try to set a sharepoint user/pass as default under linked server configuration?

Comment: Thanks Paulo - there was no error message. I've tried a number of options, including putting my domain account details in. Sharepoint is controlled by our Active Directory and I use windows authentication on SQL server, so it "should" have passed through the same userid and password.

Comment: I connected to the list using Access 2010 and the resulting connection string is different from the connnection string you are using. `WSS;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=http://server/site;LIST={8FF6B4DF-4B9C-42B5-8297-921D908654F2};VIEW=;RetrieveIds=Yes;TABLE=listName`